# AKS MySQL SSL problems (nodejs,knex)

Tags: mysql, azure, ssl, kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to provide SSL CA cert for MySQL in my applications via envvars in Azure Kubernetes, but i keep getting the following error logs.

```
NAME: RollbackError
CODE: HANDSHAKE_SSL_ERROR
MESSAGE: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I followed everything what they said in docs, I can connect to it with MySQL client from terminal, so the cert is okay.

Thats what I have in my deployment.yml:

```
....
env:
  - name: database__connection__ssl__ca
    value: "content_of_ssl_ca_cert_file" 
....
```

According to MySQL & knexjs docs for NodeJS thats the correct way to do it, it accepts strings not files or path for the file. 
Anyone any ideas?

So, I finally managed to solve this 'trivial' issue.

```
....
    env:
      - name: database__connection__ssl__ca
        value: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n...\n...-----END CERTIFICATE-----" 
....
```

Breaklines were needed.

Comment: I copied the text from the SSL cert file, and I put that into an environment variable which creates the needed object to connect to the database. If I disable SSL connection in azure its working good and functions fine. I assume theres something with the cert as a string.
[Azure MySQL SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl) -> I'm working with the linked article. In Step1 you can see the SSL cert, thats what I'm working with.

Comment: well, if you are doing it like that you need to parse it from the text into file or object

Comment: according to mysql docs, it waits for it as string, no parse needed. Or can you provide me an example what you mean?

Comment: I copied the content from the ca file and thats what I give provided as input.
Edit: I modified the code snippet above.

Comment: Finally I found a solution to this problem. You need to provide the input like this: `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n....\n....\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"`. Breaking lines is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the previous one :) pressed enter a bit before.

Comment: create an answer, instead of a comment and accept it, please ;)

Comment: Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already edited the question, but here is the solution:

```
....
    env:
      - name: database__connection__ssl__ca
        value: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n...\n...-----END CERTIFICATE-----" 
....
```

Breaklines are needed, when you want to copy the content from the cert file and provide it via envvars as string. `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` also have to be there.